# Графический отклик на нажатие на группу в ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Можно ли получить графический отклик при нажатии на группу в ExpandableListView в таком же стиле, как и отклик при нажатии на дочерний элемент в группе или в элемент в обычном ListView?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду ripple эффект?

Comment: да, именно его. не знал, что так называется :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Подключите библиотеку для ripple анимации. Например [Material Ripple Layout](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple)
2. Оберните разметку элемента группы в предоставляемый библиотекой элемент разметки.